# adding sound to html5 files in adobe animate

Tags: html, adobe, fla

I making tutorials. And ı prepair graphic and animation now ı want to add my sound animate.  How can ı Add sound my html5 files in adobe animate? I drag drob in my frames not working browser downloaded my mp3 files. how can ı solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution. Adobe animate new version properties menu is different. I find audition compenent's menu in properties. I added picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxPlQ.png)